# Functional way to execute a sub-array with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there a more functional way of doing the below, perhaps with Ramda?

```
var time = 100;

sequenceInstruments.forEach(function(instrument){
    if(instrument.on)
    {
       playInstrument(time, instrument.duration);
    }
})
```

Comment: Please note that you can avoid `if` statements without an `else` branch with `Array.prototype.filter`. Just compose `map` with `filter`. If you want to avoid the intermediate array as well, just use the transducer implementations of them.

Comment: "execute a sub-array" ?

Answer (score 3):

By only utilising functions from Ramda in a point-free manner your example would look something like this.

```
const play = R.forEach(R.when(R.prop('on'),
                              R.compose(R.partial(playInstrument, [time]),
                                        R.prop('duration'))))
play(sequenceInstruments)
```

However I often think it can be better to dial it back a little, where the use of an anonymous function could perhaps make the code more readable and convey the intent more clearly.

```
const play = R.forEach(R.when(R.prop('on'), i => playInstrument(time, i.duration)))

play(sequenceInstruments)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Scott Christopher that the point-ful solution is easier to understand than any points-free version you're likely to come up with, if you are interested in developing a point-free version, and if you'd like `time` to be a parameter to your final function, Ramda offers  a function that might help, [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith).  (There's also a related function, [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) useful for slightly different circumstances.)  This depends upon your `playInstrument` function being curried:

```
const play = R.useWith(R.forEach, [
  playInstrument, 
  R.compose(R.pluck('duration'), R.filter(R.prop('on')))
]);

play(100, sequenceInstruments);
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20playInstrument%20%3D%20curry%28%28time%2C%20duration%29%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%60playing%20at%20%24%7Btime%7D%20for%20%24%7Bduration%7D%60%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20sequenceInstruments%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27French%20Horn%27%2C%20on%3A%20true%2C%20duration%3A%2025%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27Javanese%20Gamelan%27%2C%20on%3A%20false%2C%20duration%3A%2070%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27Vibraphone%27%2C%20on%3A%20false%2C%20duration%3A%2030%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27Hammond%20B3%27%2C%20on%3A%20true%2C%20duration%3A%2060%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27Kazoo%27%2C%20on%3A%20true%2C%20duration%3A%2015%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20play%20%3D%20R.useWith%28R.forEach%2C%20%5BplayInstrument%2C%20R.compose%28R.pluck%28%27duration%27%29%2C%20R.filter%28R.prop%28%27on%27%29%29%29%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aplay%28100%2C%20sequenceInstruments%29%0A)**.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ftor: `filter` will allow you to compose in a more linear fashion, which leads to totally readable point-free code.

```
const play = pipe(
    filter(prop('on')),           // take only the instruments that are 'on'
    map(prop('duration')),        // take the duration of each of those
    forEach(playInstrument(100))  // play'm all
);

play(sequenceInstruments);
```

This is assuming `playInstruments` is curried already.

With `lodash/fp`'s shorthands you could even do this:

```
const play = pipe(
    filter('on'),
    map('duration'),   
    forEach(playInstrument(100))
);
```

Comment: Pluses for the nice simple pipeline, Minuses for the scary overloaded "shorthands".

Comment: @ScottSauyet I understand your POV. Ramda has a "purist" functional approach, whereas one might call Lodash's more "pragmatic". I don't get scared too easily ;)

Comment: Perhaps, but that's what jQuery has claimed for years too.  Somehow it seems to be sinking under all that weight.  Regardless, this is a nice solution!